# What is the difference between addMembers(...) and setMembers(...) in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

What is the difference between using SmartGWT's `addMembers` vs. `setMembers` methods for adding components to a form layout?

```java
mainLayout.addMember(northLayout);
mainLayout.addMember(southLayout);
```

or

```java
mainLayout.addMembers(northLayout, southLayout);
```

vs.

```java
mainLayout.setMembers(northLayout,southLayout);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It look's like `setMembers()` removes previous members and then adds new. But you should check docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#IbhKj4VngGk/trunk/main/src/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/Layout.java&q=setmembers%20package:http://smartgwt%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=1039 in the end, `setMembers` call `addMember` for each one, plus removing existing

Comment: true!! I took a look at the javadoc but it didn't occur to me to check out the source code. Thanks!!